# JavaScript Toggle Visibility Requires Two Clicks

Tags: javascript, html

Working in the Google+ Hangouts API and I'm trying to simply toggle the visibility of a div. Got it working, but it requires two clicks before firing (then requires only one click back and forth thereafter). This seems to be a common toggle problem, but the solution always differs. Probably something easy. Little help? Thanks!

```
<script>
//Fetches and displays participants
function showParticipants() {
  var participants = gapi.hangout.getParticipants();

  var retVal = '<p>Participants: </p><ul>';

  for (var index in participants) {
    var participant = participants[index];

    if (!participant.person) {
      retVal += '<li>A participant not running this app</li>';
    }
    retVal += '<li>' + participant.person.displayName + '</li>';

  }

  retVal += '</ul>';

//Toggles visibility of participantsDiv
  var div = document.getElementById('participantsDiv');
  if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }

  div.innerHTML = retVal;

}

function init() {
  // When API is ready...                                                         
  gapi.hangout.onApiReady.add(
      function(eventObj) {
        if (eventObj.isApiReady) {
          document.getElementById('showParticipants')
            .style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
      });
}

// Wait for gadget to load.                                                       
gadgets.util.registerOnLoadHandler(init);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible scenario i can see is when your div is hidden initially by other means say with css. This can happen since your comparison `if (div.style.display !== 'none')` will succeed as display property will mostly be empty or undefined (based on browser) and it will apply `none` to display then onwards it will start working fine due to your comparison.

Try this way:

```
if (div.style.display && div.style.display !== 'none') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
} else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EYfm/)**

or just simplify it to:

```
    var div,display;
    div = document.getElementById('participantsDiv');
    display = div.style.display;
    div.style.display = (display && display !== 'none') ? 'none' : 'block';
```

Here in the above example i have provided a css class initially to hide the div. Remove it and see the same behavior happening.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because `participantsDiv` doesn't have the `display` property defined before you do the `if(display !== 'none')`.  If that's the case it's firing twice because that statement is returning FALSE when it sees that a NULL value is of a different type than your string value.